# Python equivalent of Matlab shiftdim()

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, equivalent

I am currently converting some Matlab code to Python and I am wondering if there is a similar function to Matlab's [`shiftdim(A, n)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html)

> B = shiftdim(A,n) shifts the dimensions of an array A by n positions. shiftdim shifts the dimensions to the left when n is a positive integer and to the right when n is a negative integer. For example, if A is a 2-by-3-by-4 array, then shiftdim(A,2) returns a 4-by-2-by-3 array.

Comment: In Python it is far less important to write down your code as Matrix operation. In Matlab you want to avoid loops wherever possible as they are slow. If the shiftdim was used to transform your Problem into a Matrix operation, there is probably a different, more pythonic approach to that.

Comment: @user_na, he is probably using numpy, which has similar matrix capabilities.

Comment: off hand it looks like `np.transpose` will handle it.  But it will take some thinking to come up with the right order.  Start with the docs, and experiment with small examples. e.g. `arr.transpose(2,0,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use numpy you can use `np.moveaxis`.

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
>>> x = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))
>>> np.moveaxis(x, 0, -1).shape
(4, 5, 3)
>>> np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0).shape
(5, 3, 4)
```

> **numpy.moveaxis(a, source, destination)[source]**
>
> ```
> Parameters
>
> a:        np.ndarray 
>           The array whose axes should be reordered.
>
> source:   int or sequence of int
>           Original positions of the axes to move. These must be unique.
>
> destination: int or sequence of int
>              Destination positions for each of the original axes. 
>              These must also be unique.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`shiftdim`'s function is a bit more complex than shifting axes around.

- For input `shiftdim(A, n)`, if n is positive, shift the axes to the left by n (i.e., rotate), but if n is negative, shift the axes to the right and append trailing dimensions of size 1.
- For input `shiftdim(A)`, remove any trailing dimensions of size 1.

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np

def shiftdim(array, n=None):
    if n is not None:
        if n >= 0:
            axes = tuple(range(len(array.shape)))
            new_axes = deque(axes)
            new_axes.rotate(n)
            return np.moveaxis(array, axes, tuple(new_axes))
        return np.expand_dims(array, axis=tuple(range(-n)))
    else:
        idx = 0
        for dim in array.shape:
            if dim == 1:
                idx += 1
            else:
                break
        axes = tuple(range(idx))
        # Note that this returns a tuple of 2 results
        return np.squeeze(array, axis=axes), len(axes)
```

Same examples as the Matlab docs

```
a = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 2, 3, 5))
print(shiftdim(a, 2).shape)      # prints (3, 5, 4, 2)
print(shiftdim(a, -2).shape)     # prints (1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5)

a = np.random.uniform(size=(1, 1, 3, 2, 4))
b, nshifts = shiftdim(a)
print(nshifts)                   # prints 2
print(b.shape)                   # prints (3, 2, 4)
```